# Resource limits getting enforced only for processes in user's terminal not for su [user] from root's terminal

Tags: systemd, cgroups, limit, alma-linux

Cgroups v2 is enabled in almalinux 9.1 with kernel 5.14.0-70.22.1.el9_0.x86_64 and systemd 250 (250-12.el9_1.3).

**Content of `/etc/systemd/system/user-1002.slice.d/override.conf`:**

```ini
[Unit]
Description=User Slice for UID 1002

[Slice]
CPUAccounting=1
MemoryAccounting=1
IOAccounting=1
TasksAccounting=1
CPUQuota=70%
MemoryMax=1G
MemoryHigh=1G
IOReadBandwidthMax=/ 1G
IOWriteBandwidthMax=/ 1G
IOReadIOPSMax=/ 1000
IOWriteIOPSMax=/ 1000
TasksMax=200

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Every value is getting enforced for the user when I test them by running some commands from the user's terminal. But they don't work after I run the same commands from the root's terminal after doing `su` to that user. They also dont work when a user's process is started from a PHP script using `putenv('user_uid');`.

How do I make them work for all the processes of that user no matter how they start? Do I have to add some service file in `/etc/systemd/user`? Please help.